# RavenDB v3 persist Database Creation

Tags: persistence, ravendb

My program does the following:

1. Creates a new EmbeddedDocument store

   ```
   docStore = new DocumentStore
   {
       DefaultDatabase = "Default",
       Url = url
   };
   docStore.Conventions.DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites;
   docStore.Initialize();
   ```
2. Creates a new database within that document store

   ```
   using (var session = docStore.OpenSession())
   {
       docStore.DatabaseCommands.GlobalAdmin.CreateDatabase(
           new DatabaseDocument
           {
               Id = name,
               Settings = settings
           });

       session.SaveChanges();
   }
   ```
3. Starts up a smuggler process that imports data from a ravendump file into the newly created database.

When I navigate to localhost:port while step 2 and 3 are occuring, I see the database get created and the documents get put into the database.

Now, once that process spins down, and I attempt to reconnect to the embedded database, everything is gone--It's like the database creation and import never took place.  What am I missing?  Do I need to call Save on something?

Comment: Did you create the database in memory?
Did you shut down the embedded process in which RavenDB is running?

Comment: It is not created in memory, but yes I do shut down the process.  Once smuggler finishes I call dispose on the documentstore.  Do I need to wait before I do that?  Should I not call dispose but something else?